# Invisible spaces in PHP function result

Tags: php, function, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm working on making one of my first wordpress themes, but I seem to be encountering a weird issue. Whenever I call one of my functions with PHP, the return (when viewing the page) has a lot of white space (invisible characters). For some of the things I'm trying to do, it causes problems. Here's an example of one of my functions, the rest are built just like it.

```
 // Get YouTube Username
 function soc_youtube() {
 global $up_options;
 ?>

 <?php if($up_options->soc_youtube){ ?>
  <?php echo $up_options->soc_youtube; ?>
  <?php
  }
 }
```

That code generated this result:

[image: Look at all of the white space]

Update: Fixed

Solution: Use less tags and cut down on breaks in code

Comment: Remind me, why exactly are you entering and exiting the parser all the time? I don't see any markup in between!

Comment: I think this is chrome specific; if you're referring to the `"        testyoutube  "` but I've also wondered why

Answer (score 2):

Everything *outside* the `php` tags is pushed through directly to the output, *including* all your line breaks. To avoid that, leave the line breaks inside the PHP code:

```
 <?php if($up_options->soc_youtube){
 ?><?php
   echo $up_options->soc_youtube;
 ?><?php   //...
```

(In your example, I don't see the need to close any of the tags at all, though. You could just have everything inside one set of tags.)

Answer (score 2):

First, there is no need to end a php block and start it right back up again with nothing in between... especially on **every single line**. Try getting rid of those first and see if that makes a difference:

```
// Get YouTube Username
function soc_youtube() {
    global $up_options;
    if($up_options->soc_youtube){ 
        echo $up_options->soc_youtube;
    }
}
```

Next, if that doesn't work, try doing `var_dump($up_options->soc_youtube);` and see what's there and figure out why.

Comment: @Matt, if an answer works, generally you accept it. Either mine or Kerrek's should work.